# Ubuntu: I accepted all lisences but still get SDK error

Tags: android, cordova, sdk

I was trying out for the first time to create a dummy app. I installed the required components including cordova, android studion etc. Intially there was an issue of licenses not being accepted. I went to the Adroid/Sdk/tools/bin folder and sdkmanager and accepted the licenses. After accepting the licenses:

```
Warning: File /home/mauricewaka/.android/repositories.cfg could not be loaded.  
All SDK package licenses accepted.======] 100% Computing updates...
```

I still get this error:

```
Checking Java JDK and Android SDK versions
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=undefined (recommended setting)
ANDROID_HOME=/usr/lib/android-sdk (DEPRECATED)
Subproject Path: CordovaLib
Subproject Path: app

> Configure project :app
WARNING: The specified Android SDK Build Tools version (27.0.1) is ignored, as it is below the minimum supported version (28.0.3) for Android Gradle Plugin 3.3.0.
Android SDK Build Tools 28.0.3 will be used.
To suppress this warning, remove "buildToolsVersion '27.0.1'" from your build.gradle file, as each version of the Android Gradle Plugin now has a default version of the build tools.
Observed package id 'build-tools;debian' in inconsistent location '/usr/lib/android-sdk/build-tools/27.0.1' (Expected '/usr/lib/android-sdk/build-tools/debian')
Observed package id 'build-tools;debian' in inconsistent location '/usr/lib/android-sdk/build-tools/27.0.1' (Expected '/usr/lib/android-sdk/build-tools/debian')
Checking the license for package Android SDK Build-Tools 28.0.3 in /usr/lib/android-sdk/licenses
Warning: License for package Android SDK Build-Tools 28.0.3 not accepted.
Checking the license for package Android SDK Platform 28 in /usr/lib/android-sdk/licenses
Warning: License for package Android SDK Platform 28 not accepted.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Failed to install the following Android SDK packages as some licences have not been accepted.
     build-tools;28.0.3 Android SDK Build-Tools 28.0.3
     platforms;android-28 Android SDK Platform 28
  To build this project, accept the SDK license agreements and install the missing components using the Android Studio SDK Manager.
  Alternatively, to transfer the license agreements from one workstation to another, see http://d.android.com/r/studio-ui/export-licenses.html

  Using Android SDK: /usr/lib/android-sdk

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 14s
/home/mauricewaka/MyApp/hello/platforms/android/gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Failed to install the following Android SDK packages as some licences have not been accepted.
     build-tools;28.0.3 Android SDK Build-Tools 28.0.3
     platforms;android-28 Android SDK Platform 28
  To build this project, accept the SDK license agreements and install the missing components using the Android Studio SDK Manager.
  Alternatively, to transfer the license agreements from one workstation to another, see http://d.android.com/r/studio-ui/export-licenses.html

  Using Android SDK: /usr/lib/android-sdk

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 14s
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
yes | sdkmanager --licenses
```

to accept all licenses

and then build again. Hope this helps.

if you get

```
sdkmanager: command not found
```

Then this means you need to add the following folder to your PATH

```
$ANDROID_SDK_HOME/tools/bin
```

that's where the sdkmanager lives.

The $ANDROID_SDK_HOME needs to be replaced by the directory android sdk is in -- was ~/Android/Sdk/ in my case on ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Hope it helps.

Comment: Using ubuntu 18.04 LTS, got this error; sdkmanager: command not found

Answer (score 0):

This kinda worked:

I typed and entered;

```
touch ~/.android/repositories.cfg
```

before typing:

```
./sdkmanager --licenses
```

Also went to Adnroid/Sdk/tools/bin

```
then typed ./sdkmanager "platforms;android-26"
```

You can also use "platforms;android-28" etc

After this restarted the terminal and it worked.